# How to create a time series in Access and can use it in a query

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

**The facts:**

I use Access 2013, but it must be run in Access 2007 aswell.

I have the following 3 tables:

Order:

```
Id      DateFrom        DateTo  
1       2014-12-01      2015-03-01
2       2014-01-02      2015-03-01
3       2015-01-03      2015-03-01
```

Stock:

```
Id      Label       Amount
1       Product1    20
2       Product2    10
```

OrderStock:

```
Id      OrderId     StockId     Amount
1       1           1           10
2       2           1           5
3       2           2           5
4       3           2           5
```

The users input:

- DateFrom: 2015-01-01
- DateTo: 2015-01-03
- StockIds: 1 and 2

**The question:**

It's possible to create a 'temporary' table for a sub-query with dates from X to Y? From the user input, which would look like this:

```
dates
2015-01-01
2015-01-02
2015-01-03
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
Date        StockLabel  AmountInUse     AmountAvailable
2015-01-01  Product1    10              10
2015-01-01  Product2    0               10
2015-01-02  Product1    15              5
2015-01-02  Product2    5               5
2015-01-03  Product1    15              5
2015-01-03  Product2    10              0
```

How would the query look like, if it is even possible in Access without VBA?

Comment: Have you tried to create query via Query wizard?

Comment: @MaciejLos, there is no way the query wizard is powerful enough to do what he's asking for here.

Comment: While a real DBMS would be able to generate days using proprietary functions, I think access may be relegated to creating a [calendar table as in this solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16307035/2589202)

Comment: @paqogomez, it's only partially true. If the relationships between tables are properly set, the query wizard included into Access executable, can handle it ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos exactly, it requires tables to do it.  Whereas a real DBMS could generate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Create a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Tens]+[Ones] AS Factor, 
    10*Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) AS Tens, 
    Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) AS Ones
FROM 
    msysobjects AS Uno, 
    msysobjects AS Deca;
```

Save it as qdyFactor.
Then create this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    DateAdd("d",[Factor],[DateFrom]) AS Dates
FROM 
    qdyFactor
WHERE 
    qdyFactor.Factor Between 0 And DateDiff("d",[DateFrom],[DateTo]);
```

This will create the list of dates.
Finally, use this to filter and sum from your other tables.

Comment: First query produces cartesian product (CROSS JOIN) which is not desired.

Comment: It is desired. That what makes it work out of the box. Of course, you can create a table holding a sequence of number if you like.

Comment: As it is, the second query will only select up to 10 dates.  Instead, the two reference to `[Ones]` should be changed to `[Factor]`.