# Staff Attendance Registry Query MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, time-and-attendance

I am doing a Staff Attendance Registry using MS Access and have these fields for the Time_Registry Table:

```
ID (Autonumber)
EMPNO (Employee Number)
AttendanceDate (Date)
TimeIn (Time)
Timeout (Time)
Remarks (String).
```

Now, I wanted to do a report based on a query which will display to me a whole month and the recorded attendance of a staff like:

```
EmpNo   Date            Day     Time In   Time Out   Remarks
123    01/01/2017      Sunday     
123    02/01/2017      Monday    8:00AM    5:00PM    
123    03/01/2017      Tuesday   8:00AM    5:00PM    
123    04/01/2017      Wednesday 8:00AM    5:00PM    
123    05/01/2017      Thursday  8:00AM    5:00PM    
123    06/01/2017      Friday    8:00AM    5:00PM  
123    07/01/2017      Saturday    
123    08/01/2017      Sunday    
123    08/01/2017      Monday    8:00AM    5:00PM
```

As you can see, Saturday and Sunday have no records because it's weekend. Querying for all the records would in January would not show me Saturday and Sunday as blank.

Hope you can help me with.

Comment: Join to a calendar table.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835890/how-to-create-a-time-series-in-access-and-can-use-it-in-a-query) if you don't want to create a calendar table.