# Split range of dates into individual records, keeping IDs

Tags: sql, vba, date, ms-access-2010, range

I am working with an Access 2010 db that has a table with associate names with a range of dates that the employee has requested off, formatted as follows:

Table `DateRanges`

```
 Name--| StartDate | EndDate  
 Joe---| 12/20/13  | 12/22/13   
 Sue---| 12/24/13  | 12/26/13  
 Guy---| 12/30/13  | 01/02/14
```

I'm trying to make a query that will change the data to have an individual record for each date, but also keep the appropriate name with each record. Like this:

Table `Separated`

```
Name -- DatesOff  
Joe ----- 12/20/13   
Joe ----- 12/21/13   
Joe ----- 12/22/13   
Sue ----- 12/24/13   
Sue ----- 12/26/13   
Guy ----- 12/30/13   
................   
Guy ----- 01/02/13
```

I've seen a few different examples here regarding splitting just date ranges, but not bringing along an employee name/id with it. Any ideas? I'm open to using SQL or VBA to get it done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a table that contains each day and join it to your `DateRanges` table like so:

```
SELECT
   dr.Name,
   d.DateValue AS DatesOff
FROM
   Days d
INNER JOIN
   DateRanges dr
   ON (d.DateValue BETWEEN dr.StartDate AND dr.EndDate)
```

Comment: Here is the days table 

`select distinct convert(datetime,'2013-01-01') + number
from master..spt_values 
where type = 'p'
and convert(int,number) < 365`

Comment: By "that contains each day" do you mean every day of the year?... I have a table called "AllDays" if that's what you mean. You'll have to forgive my Novice level with SQL... I'm not sure what the "Days d" portion of your reponse means.

Comment: Thanks for the collaboration, folks! I was making it WAY more complicated than it needed to be. Simple is always best.

Comment: @AnalyzeThis See if these are useful to you: [CreateTable_calendar and LoadCalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296078/using-start-date-and-end-date-in-access-query/9303628#9303628).  With your sample table and my calendar table, Nicarus' query strategy returns what you want. (but Guy is off for most of 2013?)  Nice job, Nicarus.  +1

Comment: Haha... yah, that was supposed to be an EndDate of 01/02/14. I didn't notice until I received 300+ records in my query... I'll check out your Calendar that you've got built. I had already built my Calendar form, but it's always good to compare. Thanks again!