# Find the missing dates - vba Sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to spot which student didn't submit his task and for what date. I want to check for every student whether current or not. I don't mind if the answer is in sql or vba code. More specification below:

```
Task Table
-------------------------------
SubID  |ID | Task  | Date 
-------------------------------
1      |1  | Dance | 01-01-2014
2      |1  | Sing  | 02-01-2014
3      |1  | shout | 05-01-2014
4      |2  | try   | 02-01-2014
5      |3  | Okay  | 01-01-2014
6      |2  | random| 06-01-2014
8      |4  |Jumping| 01-01-2014
9      |4  | try   | 02-01-2014
10     |4  | Piano | 03-01-2014
11     |4  | try   | 04-01-2014
12     |4  | guitar| 05-01-2014
13     |4  | try   | 06-01-2014

Student table --the Date is in the dd-mm-yyyy format. - also it is a date/time datatype

ID | Name | Current
--------------------
1  | Ron  | YES
2  | sqlJ | YES
3  | jque | NO
4  | holy | YES
5  | htdoc| YES
```

Desired Result:

Who Didn't submit their task between `01-01-2014` and `06-01-2014`

```
ID | Date
---------------
1  | 03-01-2014
1  | 04-01-2014
1  | 06-01-2014
2  | 01-01-2014
2  | 03-01-2014
2  | 04-01-2014
2  | 05-01-2014
3  | 02-01-2014
3  | 03-01-2014
3  | 04-01-2014
3  | 05-01-2014
3  | 06-01-2014
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT w.ID, w.Date, student.[first name], student.[last name], student.[id]
FROM tasktbl AS w 
     right join student 
           on w.id = student.[id];

//I was thinking of using a vba-for loop to iterate over the range of date and store it in an array spot every Id that doesn't have a date but it didn't work out quite well.
```

Any help ranging from pseudo-code to sql-code to vba-code (basically any hint towards my quest) will be appreciated

Comment: how do you determine if a task has been completed based on the Task Table data?  your output has 5 entries for ID = 3, but your data only has 1 ID = 3 in it.

Comment: it is based on the task table data. My output is right because everyone is supposed to have 6 entries from 01-01-2014 to 06-01-2014 inclusive. so If in the task table, there is a missing date within that range then the output will show the missing date which in this case, ID =3 has five missing dates.

Comment: dd-mm-yyyy format. i will specify it in my question

Comment: Is the *Date* field text or Date/Time datatype?

Comment: yhup it is a date/time datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a calendar table which contains one row for each date.  Cross joining that table with *student*, and restricting the date range to your 6 values gave me 30 rows (6 dates times 5 students):

```sql
SELECT sub.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT c.the_date, s.ID
        FROM tblCalendar AS c, student AS s
        WHERE c.the_date Between #1/1/2014# And #1/6/2014#
    ) AS sub
```

Then I used that as a subquery and `LEFT JOIN`ed it to *tasktbl*.  So the rows where the "right side" is Null, are those where a student did not complete a task on the date in question.

```sql
SELECT sub.ID AS student_id, sub.the_date
FROM
    (
        SELECT c.the_date, s.ID
        FROM tblCalendar AS c, student AS s
        WHERE c.the_date Between #1/1/2014# And #1/6/2014#
    ) AS sub
    LEFT JOIN tasktbl AS t
    ON (sub.ID = t.ID) AND (sub.the_date = t.Date)
WHERE t.ID Is Null
ORDER BY sub.ID, sub.the_date;
```

Comment: The procedures I used to create and load my *tblCalendar* can be found at [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9303628/77335)

Comment: ... this is the exact same thing as my answer, but with the syntax slightly altered

Comment: It is **not** the exact same thing.  Your query pulls the reference dates from *taskTable*; mine uses a separate calendar table with one row for every date.  Mine is also valid Access SQL; yours is not.

Comment: but he doesn't specify that he has a calendar table.  if he doesn't IRL, he should set one up (for other uses apart from just this question...), but that is outside of the scope of what info was provided in this question

Comment: @iliketocode your initial code wasn't even close to this one. and #hansup I tweaked your answer and created the additional table. Now I am just gonna use vba code to populate the date as time goes on. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without any VBA.

```
select s.id, t.date
from 
( --this will populate every possible date, for every student
    select distinct s.id 
    from students s
) s
cross join 
(
    select distinct t.date
    from taskTable t
) t
left join taskTable tt on s.id = tt.id and t.date = tt.date
where tt.date is null
--(optional) order by clause, if needed
```

Essentially what this is doing is pulling one entry for each possible student (from the "s" table) and one entry for each possible date (from the "t" table) and doing a cross join, which generates a result set with a row containing each possible date for each possible student.  By left joining this back to the taskTable (where the taskTable's date field is null) will only return the entries from the cross join table that do **not** have tasks associated with them.

I would also recommend you re-think the design of the TaskTable, and instead of tracking only completed tasks, track all tasks and add a field "completed" which stores if the task has been completed (Yes) or not (No).

Comment: exactly my problem, the task varies. I have like 2000 task codes... Try and okay where just examples

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast did they all have exactly the same tasks, on the same dates?  ex. on 1/1/14, everyone was supposed to have a 'Dance' task?

Comment: the task are assigned randomly ... everyone studies anything he wants when he wants. so there is no supposed task for a supposed day. All i want is to see what dates are missing from the task table not what task are missing.

Comment: this is good code but if no one fills the timesheet then we are screwed because it wont find the date in the tasktable hence it will think okay, no need for timesheets at that point and you know students, once they figure this out, they will never fill their timesheets.

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast yes, if no one completed a task on a date, that date would be omitted.  but your question did not specify that you were working with any other tables, or a time table for that matter, so i had to work with what i was given, and in your example there was at least 1 of each date so it worked out.  my advice would be to set up a time table if you don't have one already, they can be used for many other things